# Firefox 22 crashes because of GWT plugin

Tags: firefox, gwt, plugins, crash, registry

I am using firefox 22 and eclipse JUNO.
My application is in GWT and when i debug firefox crashes for GWT plugin and it shows following Crashing error :

This may be because of some registry problem.

```
Add-ons: gwt-dev-plugin%40google.com:1.23,%7B972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd%7D:22.0

AvailablePageFile: 12107472896

AvailablePhysicalMemory: 4837322752

AvailableVirtualMemory: 4121890816

BuildID: 20130618035212

CrashTime: 1375791681

EMCheckCompatibility: true
```

Email:

```
InstallTime: 1375789077

ProductID: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}

ProductName: Firefox

ReleaseChannel: release

SecondsSinceLastCrash: 622

StartupTime: 1375791680

SystemMemoryUsePercentage: 41

Theme: classic/1.0

Throttleable: 1

TotalVirtualMemory: 4294836224
```

URL:

```
Vendor: Mozilla

Version: 22.0
```

Can anybody please help to resolve it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem, apparently due to an update to the GWT plugin, which doesn't seem to work with Firefox 22 (latest version is Firefox 23).

What I did to fix it is start FF in failsafe mode, deactivate the GWT plugin, restart FF, force the FF 23 update from the "Help" -> "About" menu, restart FF and reactivate the GWT plugin. It seems to work well now.

Comment: I got the same problem with eclipse Indigo. Alexandre solution worked for me

Comment: this worked for me after upgrading to firefox 26 from 25